# Re-escribir una URL

Tags: .htaccess

Necesito hacer este re escritura de dominio. A su vez necesito que se mantenga todo lo que esta después de slash pensé en algo como /* pero eso no mantendría las rutas.

```
https://subdomain.domain.me/embed/gen/1018220

https://subdomain.domain.new/embed/gen/1018220
```

Comment: ¿y como es tu .htaccess ahora?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto a ver:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.me [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://subdomain.domain.new/$1 [L,R=301]
```

donde lo que hacemos es mirar el HOST al cual llega la petición, en este caso queremos saber si es `subdomain.domain.me`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.me [NC]
```

y si esa condición se cumple entonces ejecutamos la regla siguiente, que lo redirecciona mediante una cabecera 301 de HTTP (redirección permanente) hacia el nuevo subdominio manteniendo cualquier cosa que tuviera como URL a continuación del HOST:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://subdomain.domain.new/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Lo que paso es que el link a donde llega cambio el dominio, esto a su vez lo uso dentro de un iframe, quizas podria usar java script para modificarlo...
<iframe id="loaderPlay" src="https://players.dominio.me/embed/gen/1015606" allowfullscreen="" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>

Sucede ese sitio cambio el dominio su servidor no esta redirigiendo mis peticiones correctamente .

Comment: lo siento, no entiendo lo que dices, pero si ese dominio no es tuyo, lo han cambiado de sitio y de url, entonces es muy probable que ya se hayan protegido contra **iframe**.  Seguramente puedes verlo en la consola (pulsa F12 y vete a la pestaña consola para ver los errores).